# Fabric Answers Event: Total Count for Category Attribute

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

My app presents users with a collection of colors—red, green, blue, etc. When a color is tapped, I log a custom event to Fabric with the color's name as a custom attribute:

```
Answers.logCustomEvent(
    withName: "Tapped Color", 
    customAttributes: ["color": color.name]
)
```

Now, I want to know how many times a color was tapped over a given duration (week, month, year, etc).

Is there a way to do this without clicking each day on the "color" category attribute graph and adding the counts myself? As far as I can tell, there's no way to download the custom category attributes associated with the event's "Event Count" graph either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. There currently isn't a way to download the custom attributes of an event. If that changes, I'll update my answer!

Comment: Hi, Mike. Thanks for the response! What about getting the total count for a custom attribute over a given duration? Like seeing how many times the color blue was tapped this week without clicking each day of the week on the graph. Downloading the data is secondary to the question, but it would help if what my question asks isn’t possible.

Comment: Unfortunately also not possible at the moment, but we are discussing ways to make this easier.

Comment: Hi, Mike, any progress on this? Is there a way to help you make this available? This is key to me too.

Comment: @mvdb My answer is due for an edit. You would want to link Fabric into Firebase - docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/ios-export-firebase.html Then once you ship with an updated version of the app with both SDKs in it, data would flow into both and you would get the top 25 attributes.